# Twitter Storm, why is the bolt not recieving what the spout sends

Tags: java, apache-storm

I am using Twitter Storm in a project and I have a strange problem.
I have a spout with the following nextTuple code:

```
public void nextTuple()
{
    HashMap cluster = this.databaseManager.getCluster();
    System.out.println("emitted: " + cluster);
    this.collector.emit(new Values(cluster));
}
```

And a bolt which is connected to this spout with the following execute:

```
public void execute(Tuple tuple)
{
    HashMap<String, List<String>> unigrams = (HashMap)tuple.getValueByField("unigrams");
    System.out.println("received: " + unigrams);
}
```

What is emitted should be the same as what is recieved right?
So at first the output shows this:

```
emitted: {218460=[04ef110987074dc6b3e3174b9f57d980], 1702472=[04ef110987074dc6b3e3174b9f57d980]}
received: {218460=[04ef110987074dc6b3e3174b9f57d980], 1702472=[04ef110987074dc6b3e3174b9f57d980]}
```

(It is irreverent what the data means, the point is that it is emitted and received).
But then, when the emitted is changed, the received is the same:

```
emitted: {13788873=[aa2ec732b5b64b25be81abe79d2176bb], 2293158=[aa2ec732b5b64b25be81abe79d2176bb], 218460=[04ef110987074dc6b3e3174b9f57d980], 1702472=[04ef110987074dc6b3e3174b9f57d980]}
received: {218460=[04ef110987074dc6b3e3174b9f57d980], 1702472=[04ef110987074dc6b3e3174b9f57d980]}
```

I am banging my has to why it doesn't work in the second case.
Furthermore, the output is printing a lot more from the nextTuple than it is from the execute.

Any ideas why this is?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that I found found was to convert the HashMap to a string, before sending, and then convert back into a HashMap in the bolt.

Comment: How did you add the values to your map? The problem is mainly there. Within the same JVM, bolts ans spouts keep the same java instance (I think there is no kryo serialization for optimization), beware of concurrency problems when writing / reading from tuples (especially a non concurrent hashmap)! Your fix is basically a deep copy of a tuple value to suppress any concurrency problem (no memory ref here).

Comment: The hashmap was local to the bolt. So there are no concurrency issues.

Comment: No you are wrong: if you get the hashmap from the tuple, it means it has been pushed from another element (bolt / spout) before which builds it / modify it: it is "shared" within the same JVM.

Comment: Apologies...i misunderstood you. Yes that is probably what happened.